# ¿Para que sirve el metodo this en Java?

Tags: java, método, objeto, constructor, this

Hola me hacen hacer ejercicios con el metodo **this**. Por lo que tengo entendido en un constructor entres las parentesis"()" tenes que declarar los campos a completar, por que luego debo escribirlos nuevamente con metodo **this**.

```java
    public class Coche {
    private int CERO_KM;
    private int ANO_ACTUAL;
    private static int cantidadCoches;
    private String marca;
    private String modelo;
    private int kilometros;
    private int ano;
    private double precio;

    public Coche(String marca, String modelo, int kilometros, int ano, double precio){
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.kilometros = kilometros;
        this.ano = ano;
        this.precio = precio;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola!, esta información podría serte de gran ayuda :) [Java this vs this()](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/java-this-vs-this/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` **no es un metodo** es una palabra reservada, mas específicamente `this` es un puntero hacia la instancia del objeto.

Para entender este concepto de forma mas sencilla podemos ver a esta clase como la plantilla:

```
class Coche{
   ...
   public Coche(){
   ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Y a un objeto del tipo `Coche` como un objeto creado en base a la anterior plantilla, el cual tiene guardado cierta información:

```
Coche coche = new Coche(...parametrosParaConstruir);
```

Al momento de crear este objeto se crea un puntero hacia ese objeto general, pero al momento de programar la clase posiblemente sea necesario usar los datos asignados en el constructor de la clase:

```
public Coche(String marca, String modelo, int kilometros, int ano, double precio){
    this.marca = marca;
    this.modelo = modelo;
    this.kilometros = kilometros;
    this.ano = ano;
    this.precio = precio;
}
```

Si estuviesemos en el lenguaje de programación `javascript` debo decirte que `this` es completamente necesario para referirse a metodos o atributos de una clase.

Sin embargo en `java`, esto es algo distinto, es decir, `this` es opcional en ciertos casos,  pero en tu caso en particular usar `this` **SI** es necesario y es necesario debido a que como los parametros pasados al constructor se llaman igual que los miembros de tu clase, entonces para hacer referencia a los `miembros de clase` y no a los parametros del constructor deberas usar `this`, por eso en tu constructor se usa `this`:

```
public class Coche {
    ...
    public Coche(String marca, String modelo, int kilometros, int ano, double precio){
        this.marca = marca;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.kilometros = kilometros;
        this.ano = ano;
        this.precio = precio;
    }
    ...
}
```

Sin embargo si tus parámetros no tuviesen el mismo nombre que los atributos de tu clase entonces puedes hacer la misma asignación de esta manera y es completamente valido en `java`:

```
public class Coche {
    ...
    public Coche(String marcap, String modelop, int kilometrosp, int anop, double preciop){
        marca = marcap;
        modelo = modelop;
        kilometros = kilometrosp;
        ano = anop;
        precio = preciop;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Otro punto importante y a tener en cuenta es el siguiente:**

`this` **NO** hace referencia a la clase del objeto, si no a **su instancia**, es decir, esto de aquí:

```
Coche coche = new Coche(...parametrosParaConstruir);
coche.correr();
```

No es lo mismo que:

```
Coche.correr();
```

Nótese que en el primer ejemplo `coche.correr()` esta escrito en minúscula mientras que el segundo esta escrito en mayuscula `Coche.correr()`, pese a ser parecidos no son lo mismo, puesto que el primer ejemplo figura la referencia a un **metodo no estatico** llamado `correr` que **hace parte de cualquier instancia de la clase** `Coche`, mientras que el segundo figura la referencia a un método estático llamado `correr` que **NO hace parte de ninguna instancia de la clase Coche** y ademas hace parte de la clase en si (`Coche.correr`) y no de `coche.correr`.

Por lo cual `this` hace siempre referencia al objeto creado y no a la clase.

De hecho para poner las cosas aun mas simples podríamos decir que el rango de operación de `this` es entre los corchetes de la clase:

```
class Coche{
   //De aqui hasta:
   ...
   public Coche(){
   ...
   }
   ...
   //El final opera this
}
```

Donde aquello delimitado por llaves en `javascript` se conoce como `scope`, en `java` este concepto es algo distinto...,  en `java` estando en una clase el `scope` funciona un poco distinto... siendo que cualquier cosa que este dentro de las llaves principales de la clase tenga el mismo `scope`.

Entonces podemos usar `this` para referenciar a los metodos o atributos de la instancia de un objeto.

Sin embargo seria un poco erroneo decir que el rango de operación de `this` es todo lo que esta delimitado entre las llaves principales de la clase `Coche` en tu caso, puesto que en los metodos estaticos `this` **NO** puede usarse, haciendo que el rango de operacion de `this` enrealidad no sea toda la clase si no todos los atributos o métodos de la clase que no sean estáticos, por ejemplo:

```
class Coche{
   ...
   public Coche(){
   ...
   }

   public void correr(){
      //this funcionaria aqui.
      System.out.println(this.kilometros);
   }
   ...
}
```

Mientras que:

```
class Coche{
   ...
   public Coche(){
   ...
   }

   public static void correr(){
      //this NO funcionaria aquí.
      System.out.println(this.kilometros);   //ERROR
   }
   ...
}
```

Espero haber podido aclarar un poco sobre que es `this`... yo no uso normalmente **java** pero `this` es un concepto relativamente general en muchos lenguajes de programación.

Comment: Con respecto a porque this puede ser usado para asignar los parametros de tu constructor directamente es porque this tiene el poder de invocar al constructor de la clase dentro de si mismo, haciendo que los parametros que le pases sean asignados dinamicamente con el mismo nombre que tenian como parametros, es una forma corta de asignar los valores desde los parametros.

Answer (score 1):

Propiamente el método `this()` invoca al constructor de la clase del objeto que lo invoca durante el proceso de construcción.

> Dentro de un método de instancia o constructor, `this` es una referencia al **objeto actual** — *el objeto cuyo método o constructor ha sido invocado* —. Puedes hacer referencia a cualquier miembro del objecto actual desde dentro de un método de instancia o constructor utilizando `this`. — https://docs.oracle.com/

Ahora bien, la palabra reservada `this` hace referencia a los atributos de una instancia de la clase y no a la clase en sí, por lo que no podrá ser usada para acceder a los atributos estáticos o propios de la clase.

En tú caso, los parámetros que recibes como argumento en el constructor **no son atributos de la instancia de la clase**, por lo que lo que estarías haciendo es asignar esos valores a los atributos de tu clase.

El uso de la palabra reservada `this` sirve en casos donde puede haber un conflicto con los nombres de las variables, donde un método, en este caso el constructor, recibe parámetros con el mismo nombre que los atributos de la clase, de esta forma Java evita restringir el uso de los nombres de los campos de clase como parámetros de un método o variables con un alcance menor al de la propia clase.

Ejemplo:

```java
public class Empleado {
  public static final int PUESTO_GERENTE = 1;
  public static int PUESTO_ADMINISTRATIVO = 2;
  private int edad;
  private float salario;
  private String puesto;
  private String nombre;

  /*
   * Este constructor recibe los parametros necesarios para calcular
   * el sueldo de la instancia, una vez finalizada la construccion
   * del objeto, estos no guardan ninguna relacion con el.
   */
  public Empleado(int tipoPuesto, float descuento){
    switch(tipoPuesto){
      // Puedo acceder a un atributo de la clase con el nombre de la clase, no con this
      case(Empleado.PUESTO_GERENTE):
        this.puesto = "GERENTE";
        this.salario = 40000 - descuento;
        break;
      // No es necesario utilizar this para acceder a este recurso estatico de la clase
      case(PUESTO_ADMINISTRATIVO):
        this.puesto = "ADMINISTRATIVO";
        this.salario = 10000 - descuento;
        break;
      default:
        this.puesto ="SIN ASIGNAR";
        // En este caso el atributo de la instancia sueldo queda sin asignar
        break;
    }
    this.salario = salario,
  }

  /*
   * Este constructor recibe todos los parametros con excepción del salario
   * por lo cual lo calcula e invoca al otro constructor
   */
  public Empleado(int edadEmpleado, int tipoPuesto, String nombre, float descuento){

    // Aquí no hay necesidad de utilizar 'this' por que los nombres son distintos
    edad = edadEmpleado;

    // Esto es incorrecto por que no es un atributo de la instancia sino de la Clase
    this.PUESTO_ADMINISTRATIVO = 5;        

    this.nombre = nombre;

    // LLamada al primer constructor para calcular y asignar el sueldo
    this(tipoPuesto, descuento);
  }

  // Tambien sirve en metodos de la instancia mas no en metodos estaticos de la Clase
  public void setSueldo(float sueldo){
     this.sueldo = sueldo;
  }     

}
```

Para mas detalles te dejo el siguiente enlace de la documentación oficial:

[Using the this Keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Comment: Cabe mencionar que en el paradigma orientado a objetos se desaconseja utilizar la expresión _apuntador_ y mejor utilizar _referencia_.

Comment: ¿Por qué no se puede utilizar dicho término? Las referencias en Java son **punteros** (de forma implícita, claro). Usar ese término en Java no tiene sentido (porque no hay soporte), pero si nos enfocamos en como funciona las cosas, si tiene sentido :)

Comment: Si, son lo mismo, y claro que se puede ocupar el término, pero no se recomienda porque no refleja los principios del paradigma orientado a objetos, por lo que en muchos de los sitios que hablen sobre el tema se les mencionara como _referencias_. Lo menciono porque para alguien que esta aprendiendo Java, es muy importante tener claro los conceptos de acuerdo a la POO

Answer (score 1):

this vs this().

Hola, en el método constructor "seteas" los valores que serán asignados a las variables de instancia. 
En este caso para hacer referencia a la variable de instancia "marca" necesitas usar this.marca para asignar el nuevo valor, dado que por defecto una variable de tipo String se inicializa en null por defecto.

this() es una invocación al constructor, usando métodos cargados. Como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
public class Test {
private String marca;
private String modelo;

public Test(){
    this("Marca", "Model");    
}
public Test(String marca, String modelo){
    this.marca = marca;
    this.modelo = modelo;
}
```

}

Saludos!